# PHP PDO Login fails when inactive for long periods

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a simple PHP application running on IIS using SQL Server and PDO that I run **locally** on a Windows machine with Windows 8.1.

What I'm finding is that if the computer is left for a long period of time and then I access the application, I sometimes get the following error:

> [04-Apr-2016 13:57:33 Europe/Dublin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'username'.' in C:\Application\web\api\helpers\DB.php:21
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 C:\Application\web\api\helpers\DB.php(21): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:server=L...', 'username', 'password')
>       #1 C:\Application\web\api\helpers\DB.php(14): DB->__construct()
>       #2 C:\Application\web\api\controllers\App.php(309): DB::getInstance()
>       #3 C:\Application\web\api\index.php(49): App::ListAppWithMedia()
>       #4 {main}
>         thrown in C:\Application\web\api\helpers\DB.php on line 21

If I then refresh the page, it works fine! From the looks of the error it's as though it can't connect to the DB... Any ideas on what could cause this? I know that IIS can go idle and restart to save resources but why would it fail on the SQL Server? And then fix itself on a refresh?

The contents of the DB.php are:

```
class DB
{
    private $connection;

    private static $instance = NULL;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === NULL)
            self::$instance = new self();

        return static::$instance;
    }

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".SERVER.";Database=".DATABASE, UID, PWD);
    }

    public function query($query, $params = null)
    {
        $q = $this->connection->prepare($query);

        $execute = $q->execute($params);

        return $q;
    }

}
```

And here's an example of how this class is used:

```
class App
{
    public static function ListAppWithMedia()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Applications";

        $query = DB::getInstance()->query($sql);

        $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $rows;
    }
}
```

This all works fine normally unless the computer is left idle for a few hours.

Comment: Sounds like a DB configuration issue. Check this out: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29992/odbc-data-source-sql-server-connection-login-failed-for-user

Comment: @MonkeyZeus But the login works fine on first load and on refreshes. It only fails if the computer is left idle.

Comment: Have you attempted that "fix", restarted your computer/server/DB, and still experience the issue?

Comment: That question is about always getting the error because they hadn't enabled SQL Server Login as well as Windows Login. I have that enabled otherwise I'd have the above error all the time, but I don't!

Comment: You mean that the client computer is left idle and causes the server to fail or is it the server computer left idle and then fails no matter who the client is?

Comment: This is running locally, so client and server is the same thing.

Comment: @Cameron What happens if you leave the computer idle but instead of accessing the server directly, you create an incognito tab and use that instead (as to simulate a new client trying to use the server).

Comment: @RyanVincent how come this doesn't happen when first starting? And is there a way to prevent this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Create a PDO instance and set the error mode    
<?php
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost';
    $user = 'user';
    $password = 'pass';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    ?>
```